# How to create a dictionary from a textfile and add a value in python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a text file that has this in it the following

```
a
b
c
d
```

How can I create a dictionary and add a value so that it will be like this:

```
a is 1,
b is 2,
c is 3,
d is 4
```

I'm a beginner so I have tried to follow guides here but all the text files contain like `a 1 b 2 c 3` but mine is `a b c d`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
with open(your_file_name, "r") as f:
     data = {k: l for l, k in enumerate(f, 1)}
```

Comment: I have to use dictionary on this one. sorry, but im a beginner and just started.

Comment: @knaab, that is a dictionary

Comment: how do i print that out?

Comment: @knaab, use print over data...`print(data)`

Comment: @netwawe Thanks that did work, but how do i sort it in alphabetic order so it actually comes like this: a:1 b:2 c:3 d:4. Now i get a output like this: 'a\n': 1, , 'b\n': 2,  'c\n': 3

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered by default in python versions lower than 3.7, if that is your case use an `OrderedDict` instead